# Data insertion/update

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Assume that I have a collection such as;

```
[
  {name: "alex" , id:1 , age: 23},
  {name: "felix" , id:2 , age: 29},
  {name: "lenix" , id:3 , age: 45},
]
```

I want to write one update and insert db query which includes the following situation;

- update if `name` exists, otherwise insert it to the db; `db.collection.update({name: name_} ,{name: name_, id: id_, age: age_ }, {upsert: true})`

But the main problem is this;

I get the id and name field from client. If `name` is changed

`db.collection.update({name: name_} ,{name: name_, id: id_, age: age_ }, {upsert: true})`

gives me an error. Because, `id` remains same and it is not possible to insert a data that has new name value but same id field with the older one.

Let's make it clear with an example. I have;

```
[
  {name: "alex" , id:1 , age: 23}
]
```

From the client, name and id field comes as `alexi` and `1`.  An I request as; 
`db.collection.update({name: "alexi"} ,{name: "alexi", id: 1, age: 43}, {upsert: true})`
There is already a data with id 1. The insertion returns error.

I assign `id` field in the server;

```
if(there is id field from client)
   id_ = id;
else
   id_ = some random value
```

So in this situation, id comes from the client and I don't regenerate its value. So how can I handle this situation? As I said, I want to write a query which can insert/update data to the collection.

Answer (score 0):

if your are **mongoose** then remove **unique:true** constraint from shcema. It would allow your to add duplicate value for that field.